# Boundary conditions of steady current

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, electric-current, gauss-law, boundary-conditions

**Boundary conditions of steady current**

For  steady current we have : 
$\vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{J}(\vec{r})=0$
Or $\oint \vec{J}(\vec{r}) d\vec{r}=0$
Then How to prove that: 
$$\vec{J}(\vec{r})_{1n}=\vec{J}(\vec{r})_{2n}$$
Where $\vec{J}(\vec{r})_{in}$ is the normal component of the current density $i$ the i th medium. 
And also  How to prove that: 
$$E(\vec{r})_{1t}=E(\vec{r})_{2t}$$

Answer (score 1):

The first equation $$\vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{J}(\vec{r})=0 \tag 1$$ due to [Gauss's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem) is equivalent to $$\int_{\partial S} \vec J(\vec r)d\vec a=0 \tag 2$$ This means that there is no time change of charge enclosed in the volume. The derivation of the normal current density boundary condition follows the same path as the for the [electrical field boundary conditions](http://See,%20e.g.%20David%20J.%20Griffiths%20%22Introduction%20to%20Electromagnetics%22,%20Prentice%20Hall%201999) for the normal component of the dielectric displacement $\vec D$.

The continuity of the normal component of the stationary current density is obtained using eq. (2) with a Gaussian pill box surface enclosing the interface of the media and letting the pillbox height go to zero. In the stationary case, there is no time change of a possible interface charge. This yields $$\vec{J}(\vec{r})_{1n}=\vec{J}(\vec{r})_{2n} \tag 3$$ The continuity of the tangential component of the electric field follows from $\nabla \times \vec E=0$ and thus $\oint \vec{E}(\vec{r}) d\vec{r}=0$ and  a closed rectangular integration path at the interface which yields 
$$E(\vec{r})_{1t}=E(\vec{r})_{2t} \tag 4$$